# JSF page in subfolder can't see template

Tags: jsf-2

I've got a template in WEB-INF/templates/standardTemplate.xhtml

In my "Web Pages" root, I've got an index.xhtml which uses the template via

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/standardTemplate.xhtml">
```

The above works fine.

However I also have another page which uses the same template, but it's in a subfolder "Web Pages"/messageboard/list.xhtml

It uses exactly the same syntax/paths:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/standardTemplate.xhtml">
```

But it can't find the template and renders just the content of list.xhtml (none of the template's content).

Faces servlet is mapped to "/faces/*"

What am I doing wrong? Tried every variant I can think of but I can't get the right syntax.

Thanks

Comment: It should work just fine. Open the offending page in browser, rightclick and *View Source*. Do you see `<ui:composition>` or not? You should not see it in generated HTML output.

Comment: Ahhhhh, good idea. I DO see it. Something's not rendering the code properly. I just checked my namespaces and they look the same as they are in the working page so I would expect them to work. Do you know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, you're seeing `<ui:composition>` unparsed in the HTML output.

That can only mean that the request URL as you've in the browser address bar does not match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet`. Make sure that it matches the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet`. You've mapped it on `/faces/*`, so the URL should contain the `/faces` path prefix right after the context path.

Better would be to map the `FacesServlet` directly on `*.xhtml` so that you never need to fiddle with virtual URLs.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. It's all new to me and I missed that. It works great now thanks. Great blog by the way ;)